# Returning like count and whether current user liked a post in Cypher

Tags: neo4j

I have a possibly bone-headed question, but I'm just starting out with Neo4j, and I hope someone can help me out with learning Cypher syntax, which I've just started learning and evaluating.

I have two User nodes, and a single NewsPost node. Both users LIKE the NewsPost. I'm able to construct a Cypher query to count the likes for the post, but I'm wondering if it's also possible to check if the current user has liked the post in the same query.

What I have so far for a Cypher query is

```
match (p:NewsPost)<-[r:LIKES]-(u:User)
where id(p) = 1
return p, count(*)
```

Which returns the post and like count, but I can't figure out the other part of "has the current user liked this post". I know you're not supposed to filter on `<id>`, but I learned that after the fact and I'll go back and fix it later.

So first, is it possible to answer the "has the current user liked this post" question in the same query? And if so, how do I modify my query to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by 'current user'? Is that a property on a user node?

Comment: Hi @jjaderberg, what I mean is the current logged in user. But for this exercise, we can just match on the "email" property on the user node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smallest change to your query that adds a true/false test for a particular user liking the news post would be

```
MATCH (p:NewsPost)<-[r:LIKES]-(u:User)
WHERE ID(p) = 1
RETURN p, count(r), 0 < size(p<-[:LIKES]-(:User {email:"michael@nero.com"}))
```

This returns, in addition to your query, the comparison of 0 being less than the size of the path from the news post node via an incoming likes relationship to a user node with email address michael@nero.com. If there is no such path you get `false`, if there is one or more such paths you get `true`.

If that does what you want you can go ahead and change the query a little, for instance use `RETURN ... AS ...` to get nicer result identifiers, and so on.

Comment: This definitely works, but you say "smallest change" I could make. Are there bigger changes you'd recommend making? Also, I don't see the size operator documented at http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.3. Do you know where to find the documentation for it?

Comment: By smallest change I meant that my answer tries to illustrate a 'technique' clearly but that the same result can be achieved in other ways. F.i., you could match the user as `u2` at the top of your query and do `0 < size(p<-[:LIKES]-u2)` if that makes more sense, for instance if you also want to return that user, or if that works better with an index that you have on users, or...

Comment: @MichaelNero You know, I don't know where `size()` is documented. I've picked it up from Michael Hunger here on SO. Supposedly it is faster than alternative methods (like counting the paths) because of how it is implemented, but I don't remember reading any documentation. There are some things like that (regular expression syntax, operator precedence) that seem to have escaped the manual–if you feel industrious perhaps you could confirm whether it is documented somewhere and raise a github issue if it's not? Or edit my answer with a link if you find it.

Comment: there's http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.3/query-functions-scalar.html#functions-length, which at least *seems* to function the same way as size. Since I'm speculating, I won't edit your answer with length just yet until you or someone else confirms they are functionally equivalent.

Comment: It's not the same, I'll keep an eye out for something, official or unofficial, that documents it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [Case](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-expressions.html).

In your database you should have something unique for each user (id property, email or maybe login, I don't know), so you have to match this user, and then match the relation to the post you want, using case you can return a boolean.

#### Example:

```
Optional Match (u:User{login:"Michael"})-[r:LIKES]-(p:newPost{id:1}) 
return CASE WHEN r IS NULL THEN false ELSE true END as userLikesTopic
```

If you want to get the relation directly (to get a property in it as example) you can remove the CASE part and directly return r, if it does not exist, `null` will be returned from the query.